# Indicator Function Notations and Joint Probability Density Function

Tags: probability

I have the following exercise:

Let the Joint PDF be given as $f(x,y) = I(0 < x <2)I( x <2(1-y))$. Find $P(X > 1, Y < \frac{1}{4})$ and $P(X > Y)$.

Firstly, I do not understand this indicator function notation. To my understanding, the indicator function tells me the domain of $x$ or $y$, but in this case they are using it to define the function. So then what is the function?

[Picture of Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVM2W.png)

Comment: Id venture to guess that $I(0<x<2)$ means a value of $1$ for $0<x<2$, $0$ otherwise

Answer (score 1):

In general indicator function $I(a\leq x \leq b)$ is just defined $I(x)=1$ for $x \in [a,b]$ and $I(x) = 0$ otherwise.

So your function $f(x,y)=1$ for pairs $(x,y) \in A$, 
$$A= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x \in (0,2), x < 2(1-y) \}.$$
Otherwise  $f(x,y)=0.$

Can you now count what is needed?

**Edit:**
Now we seen that 
$$A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x \in (0,2), y \in \left(-\infty,1-\frac{x}{2} \right) \}.$$

So if $f$ is density function then must be true that 
$$\int_0^2 \int_{-\infty}^{1-x/2} 1 dydx=1,$$
which is **evidently not correct**, the integral is not finite. Did you rewrite the exercise correctly?
Also just a note, when you evaluate integral in $\mathbb R^2$ you always start to integrate from the most inner integral. Therefore the order is important, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus).)

Comment: Ah thanks for the indicator function information.  Now I am a bit confused on how the bounds will work for the double integral $\int \int_{A}$. In the exercises I have done, it has been quite clear what the bounds were for $x$ and $y$. i.e, $A = \{ (x,y) \mid 0 < x < 2, \; 1 < y < 2 \}$. In this case, $x$ is clear to me, but not $y$. We have $y < 1 - \frac{x}{2}$. So would we have: $\int_{-\infty}^{1 - \frac{x}{2}} \int_{0}^{2} f(x,y)dxdy$?

Comment: Yes but you put the integrals in bad order, it should be $ \int_{0}^{2}  \int_{-\infty}^{1 - \frac{x}{2}}f(x,y)dydx$ since you first "pick" $x$ from $(0,2)$ and then you have constraints on $y$.

Comment: Hm, I don't understand what you are saying about my order of integration. Does it matter?

Comment: I'll edit my answer and put it there.

Comment: To answer your edit, yes I am sure that I wrote it down correctly. The reason why I am confused about your order of integration is because the definition I have for a Joint PDF is $P[(X,Y) \in A] = \int \int_{A} f(x,y)dxdy$ for any region $A$ in the $xy$-plane

Comment: Then your density function is not a density. $P[(X,Y) \in A] = \int \int_{A} f(x,y)dxdy$ is just a notation, it does not say that $x$ must be "first". In fact in this notation $P[(X,Y) \in A] = \int \int_{A} f(x,y)dxdy = \int \int_{A} f(x,y)dydx$ . You have to learn something about integrals in $\mathbb R^2$. Read the wiki, at least.

Comment: I will. See my edit to my OP. Perhaps I am reading the question incorrectly?

Comment: I think there is additional condition $y>0$, so the corect density is $$f(x,y) = I(0 < x <2)I( x <2(1-y))I(y>0).$$

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help. Odd that the $y>0$ condition wasn't included, but the pretext to the exercises says "look for mistakes"